# Lubuntu no apaga,reinicia o suspende

Tags: linux

Hola muy buenas hace poco me compre este ordenador :

```
MSI PE62 8RC
```

He instalado Lubuntu en el ssd nvme, sin embargo cuando apago,reinicio o suspendo el equipo este se queda congelado, no llega a cerrar los procesos que estan activos, simplemente se queda congelado y tengo que llegar a apagar con el boton.

Comment: Esta pregunta está fuera de la temática de SOes, pero puedes mirar en [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029068/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-at-shutdown). Puedes probar a actualizar los drivers de tu gŕafica, por ejemplo...

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un problema de configuración de un equipo

Comment: Es posible que la computadora está arrancada pero no hay video (porque los drivers.).  Pruebe si puede accessarlo por TTY o Telnet.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione. El sistema no habia preinstalado el paquete :"pn-utils" que es el que usa el entorno grafico para correr este tipo de servicios